# Why can't I connect to the index page of WebIOPi?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-2, webiopi

I have a problem to view index.php of WebIOPi:

- I installed: gcc-4.7 and Python 3.2.
- Downloaded WebIOPi like so: `wget http://webiopi.googlecode.com/files/WebIOPi-0.6.0.tar.gz`
- I ran `tar xvzf WebIOPi-0.6.0.tar.gz`
- `cd WebIOPi-0.6.0`
- `sudo ./setup.sh`
- And started with this: `sudo /etc/init.d/webiopi start`

But when I go to `http://my_ip:8000`I don't find the `index.php` of WebIOPi.
Why?

Comment: To your local IP or public IP? If you are using public IP do not forget about port forwarding on your router.

Answer (score 1):

It may be late to answer, index.html is located in the folder `htdocs`
but try to reconfigure it:

```
dpkg-reconfigure webiopi
```

if it doesn't solve your problem you may find index.html in the folder that you installed in
like: `/pi/home/webiopi/htdocs/`

Answer (score 1):

As you have not specified your `config` file from `/etc/webiopi/config` it is very difficult to know where your configurations are actually working or not.

However there is also a patch which I use for **Raspberry Pi - 2 Model B** which made things very easy.

The patch is although for **WebIOPi version 0.7** but if there are internal issues which cannot be sorted you might as well go through the Patch from [DoubleBind](https://github.com/doublebind/raspi) or just follow their **README**